# MS Access to SQL Server Database conversion

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to convert Access 2016 to SQL server 2014 or 2017. I used import wizard everything is fine accept it is not copying data from the tables.

Comment: How many tables are you migrating?

Comment: 22 tables I have in my access database

Comment: Not sure how anybody can really answer this.

Comment: Use SSMA: [Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant 8.4 for Access](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54255)

Comment: Thanks for this link this is helpful. It copied everything except one table
The error is “ Cloumn'To/Form' does not allow DBNull. value'”

Comment: @Doll.  Wizards are not perfect.  You'll need to change your table definition to allow for NULL values and re-import just that table.

Comment: Thanks you all for your help. I fixed this issue by making unique Index to non unique and then i migrated the table and it copied everything without any error.

Answer (score 0):

making unique Index to non unique and then migrate the table and it will copy everything without any error.